# Probability that an event will occur at a certain time given previous data

Tags: probability, statistics

I was wondering how I would go about calculating the probability of the following scenario.
Say we have an event $X$ (for example a TV being on) which has been previously observed as follows,

Day 1 - between $t_{start1}  $ & $  t_{end1}$

Day 2 - between $t_{start2} $ & $ t_{end2}$

Day 3 - between $t_{start3} $ & $ t_{end3}$

what would the probability be that $X$ is occurring at time $x$ on day 4 - based on all previous data? (e.g. the TV is on)
$$$$
where

$t_{start}$ is the time $X$ started e.g. the TV was turned on.

$t_{end}$ is the time $X$ ended e.g. the TV was turned off.

$t_{start} $ & $t_{end}$ can only occur once a day

Comment: You need additional information. For example, does $t_1$ to $t_2$ overlap with $t_3$ to $t_4$? Does the probability depend uniformly on all the three previous days?

Comment: The probability would be based on all previous days yes. I am unsure what you mean but 'does $t_1$ to $t_2$ overlap with $t_3$ to $t_4$'. $t_1$ could be equal to $t_3$ if that's what you're referring to

Comment: Well then it would depend entirely on the $t_i’s$  and the overlap (if any). Also, does $X$ necessarily have to occur on any day?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to no. But I thought it would be easier if we assumed it did.

Comment: A possible scenario: Assume the event happen in a random time in a day, and we want to estimate the CDF/Survival function. The time in each day assume to be i.i.d.. And we only inspect the event happened or not at some specific, deterministic time, so we are only able to know that the event happen in a specific interval - which is interval censoring. So we may apply some survival model to regress on the data. If you impose too little assumption, you will need a lot of data to do a non-parametric one.

Answer (score 0):

There is nowhere near enough information to be able to answer the question. Here's a short list of some things that would be needed in order to give a good answer:

1. First, as suggested in the comments, it would be good to know something about the $t_i$ values. The situation might be different the three time intervals are all $[1, 4]$ PM versus if the first is $[1, 4]$, the second is $[2, 5]$, and the third is $[5, 8]$, for instance.
2. You said the probability is the same from day to day. Fair enough. But how are the intervals known, then? If different days are supposed to be the same, then what would it convey if (for instance) the first arrival happened between in $[1, 4]$ PM and the second happened in $[2, 5]$ PM? (Perhaps that's not actually possible, but it wasn't specified in the question.)
3. For that matter, what is the nature of the intervals themselves? What does it mean to say that $X_1$ happens in $[t_1, t_2]$? Are we *assuming* it can only happen in that interval, or was it *observed* to have happened in that interval? If it's the former, then why wouldn't we similarly *assume* something to answer the question about day 4? If it's the latter, then why give an interval at all? Why not give a specific time?
4. If (and this is a big if) we are *assuming* that $X_1$ happens in $[t_1, t_2]$ (instead of *observing* this to have happened), then what is the **distribution** of the probability? Could the event happen uniformly somewhere on that interval -- i.e. it is no more likely to be in any given part of the interval than in any other part of equal size? Or, maybe it has a Gaussian, a.k.a. normal, distribution? Note that this would be a bit problematic, because a normally distributed variable can necessarily occur at any time and cannot be contained with certainty to a finite interval.

You're asking a question that at face value sounds like a statistical question -- but even statistical questions require some nature of assumptions at the underlying data, specifically in the form of *distributions* of what has previously happened. For instance, you might assume that event times are normally distributed with some mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and that they are independent on different days. This assumption would let you take the *specific* arrival times (not windows as posed in the problem) and make some good guesses about $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$; from there, you could compute some probabilities. This is just one of several approaches you could take, of course, and it may or may not be reasonable. But the point I'm trying to make is that this question is not close to being answerable in its present form.